# Div going through fade in/fade out cycle blinks abruptly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, document-ready

I have a series of divs that fade in and out in a cycle. After it gets going it works smoothly, but when the page is first loaded, the first div that is displayed abruptly "blinks" once, before entering the smooth fade in/fade out cycle. Live example [here](http://www.rouvou.com).

**html**

```
<div id="rotate-1-1">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div id="rotate-1-2">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div id="rotate-2-1">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div id="rotate-2-2">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div id="rotate-3-1">
  <!--...-->
</div>
<div id="rotate-3-1">
  <!--...-->
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var divs = $('div[id^="rotate-1-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

        (function cycle() { 

            divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs.length;

        })();
      }, 0);
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var divs2 = $('div[id^="rotate-2-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

        (function cycle() { 

            divs2.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs2.length;

        })();
      }, 100);
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var divs3 = $('div[id^="rotate-3-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

        (function cycle() { 

            divs3.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs3.length;

        })();
      }, 200);
  });
</script>
```

What could be causing the blinking effect when the page is initially loaded?

Comment: Quick question, but should they be visible on page load? If I had to guess, without combing through that site for your css to create a fiddle, if you set them to be hidden on load and then fade in that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout` isn't necessary for the first group of divs since it's a `0 ms` timeout. That's what's causing the blinking.

Also, you should wrap your `setTimeout` around the `(function`, rather than the `var divs` instantiation. This could unnecessary cause latency.

I created a JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/noq2f5ox/2/

JS Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var divs = $('div[id^="rotate-1-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

        (function cycle() { 

            divs.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs.length;

        })();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
        var divs2 = $('div[id^="rotate-2-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

      setTimeout(function() {
        (function cycle() { 

            divs2.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs2.length;

        })();
      }, 100);
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
        var divs3 = $('div[id^="rotate-3-"]').hide(),
            i = 0;

      setTimeout(function() {
        (function cycle() { 

            divs3.eq(i).fadeIn(800)
                      .delay(3700)
                      .fadeOut(500, cycle);

            i = ++i % divs3.length;

        })();
      }, 200);
  });
```

Comment: I figured it might be related to that. Well the reason I have a setTimeout is because the other two groups are set to be slightly delayed, and I need all three to be synced so there's a 100 second difference between them (I added my full code). Is there a way to keep the setTimeout but get rid of the blinking?

Comment: @JeffCaros how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/richardgirges/noq2f5ox/2/ Remove the first 0 ms setTimeout - it's not necessary. The other two groups, keep them the same but wrap the setTimeout around the `(function cycle()` - not around the `var divs` instantiation. Is that the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to remove that 0ms timeout and/or hide the elements via CSS instead of a call to `.hide`. That way they are hidden by default on page load.

CSS:

```
div.my-divs {
  display: none;
}
```